# Facebook error 3506 "The action type likes:Like does not exist or is not approved" how i solve this?

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

im trying to use facebook built in likes via the graph api.
im using the  App Token, since the users have already logged in in my site.
here is the source im using, it uses this library
https://github.com/criso/fbgraph

```
function liker(url,profile){
 graph.setAccessToken(app_token);

  var like = {
    object: url
  };

  graph.post(profile.id + "/og.likes", like, function(err, res) {
  // returns the post id
    console.log(res); // { id: xxxxx}
  });
}
```

The app works as expected with app admin/owner me, but with any other user i get this error msg

```
 error:
  { message: '(#3506) The action type likes:Like does not exist or is not approved, so app      xxxxxxxxxx can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User yyyyyyyyyyy$
 type: 'OAuthException',
 code: 3506 }
```

my app requests the publish actions permisions from the user, that is the requirement for the built in like action from fb.

Thanks beforehand, any help will be apreciated.

Comment: So, did you get your action _approved_ by Facebook?

Comment: `or is not approved` - see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/

Comment: yeah that was the problem, i feel kind stupid lol, sorry, create an answer so i can select it as a response, and close, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to submit your actions before it is approved by Facebook, check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/

Before that, only admins, developers and testers of the application are allowed to test the action.