# Make "Like" action for Facebook post for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-networking

How can i make "Like" action for Facebook post in iOS? I receive newsfeed from FB, and i need make Like and Comment Buttons. I use `graph api`, but without Facebook SDK. 
For "Like" action i tried [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes).
Using POST i send to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB
ID]/og.likes parameters access_token and like url
```

But i receive an error:

```
{ error =     {
    code = 240;
    message = "(#240) Requires a valid user to be specified (either via
    the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.";
    type = OAuthException; }; }
```

The permissions:

```
FacebookPermissions = @"publish_stream,email,read_mailbox,user_online_presence,
friends_online_presence,user_about_me,share_item,read_stream,read_page_mailboxes,
read_friendlists,read_insights,publish_actions,user_likes,friends_likes";
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: It seems that the user was not logged in while trying to perform the request. Can you add the code used to login the user?

Comment: I find the answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479534/facebook-error-3506-the-action-type-likeslike-does-not-exist-or-is-not-approve. Thank for all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer. [Facebook error 3506 "The action type likes:Like does not exist or is not approved" how i solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479534/facebook-error-3506-the-action-type-likeslike-does-not-exist-or-is-not-approve)
thanks tkcast!