# iOS Facebook posting using Open Graph fails - error Code 102

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [this example](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBOGSampleSD) to post my story to facebook. I have my own Open Graph objects, stories though.

This worked well when I had existing login into my iPhone's native FB app. This login was the one who administers my FB app. I have everything verified including bundle ID, URL scheme, app store ID and so on.

After some time successfully posting, I started observing that my posts were successfully getting posted (response code) but not appearing in FB timeline. I played with timeline audience access and so on, but to no avail.

Then I switched the user on device FB app, and I started getting error code 102.

The response doesn't say much, except this:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102
FBAPIErrorDomain error 3506
```

I figure [from this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#errors) that this has something to do with API Session - I am **doing nothing inside my app** to obtain one, and I don't know if I should, if I am using the above example code.

What should I do to ensure I always have valid Facebook session while I post?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479534/facebook-error-3506-the-action-type-likeslike-does-not-exist-or-is-not-approve

Comment: upvote thanks. Just figured it through another of that kind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27805425/1506363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is same as what Ming Li suggested, and has been [derived from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27805425/1506363).

Before FB app approval by Facebook, one needs to add test users to perform actions related to permissions.